# In my GUI using java, I want to be able to open a pdf/doc file

Tags: java, file, user-interface

So, under my Menu bar I have an about menu item, when I click that item, I want a pdf/doc file to open up to the user.  How can I do this?

Comment: My answer solved your problem?

Answer (score 4):

This does not work?

```
Desktop.getDesktop().open(file);
```

See [`Desktop.open(File)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html#open%28java.io.File%29) for details.

Answer (score 0):

I use the code (in my own program)

```
File help = new File(FILEPATH);
if(help.exists() == false)
    throw new Exception();
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("rundll32 url.dll,FileProtocolHandler " + FILEPATH);
```

where you have to put in the FILEPATH you want.  This may be Windows-specific, not sure.  :/